# AngularUI accordion menu not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accordion

I know there are other questions about this but they don't seem to solve my problem.

This what my output is, and I thought it should be an accordion
[image: code output screeshot]

I am fairly new to Angular so I may be missing something simple, but I can't seem to see it. This is going to go into a larger app that I am making, but I wanted to get it to work outside of that first.

Any help is appreciated.

Code:

`demo.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp' >
<head>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script scr="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Accordion Test</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div ng-controller="AccordionDemo">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
            Only open one at a time
        </label>

    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <accordion-group heading="Item1" is-open="true">
                the contenct of item one
            </accordion-group>

            <accordion-group heading = {{group.title}} ng-repeat="group in groups">
              {{group.content}}
            </accordion-group>

            <accordion-group heading="{{dynamicitem}}">
                <p>The body of the accordion group lol</p>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"     ng-click="addItem()">Add new items</button>
                <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
            </accordion-group>

            <accordion-group is-open="isopen">
                <accordion-heading>
                    Open and Close <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="    {'glyphicon-chevron-down':isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen} "></i>
                </accordion-heading>
                Your content is here
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

`app.js`

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function AccordionDemo($scope){
$scope.oneAtATime = true;
$scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic member 1",
      content: "member 1 body"
    },
    {
      title :"Dynamic member 2",
      content :"member 2 body"
    }
];

$scope.dynamicitem = 'Dynamic Item';
$scope.items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
$scope.addItem = function(){
  var newItem = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item' + newItem);
};
}
```

Edit:
Is it anything to do with the

```
<accordion-group is-open="isopen">
```

block? As the isopen might not bind to anything?

Plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/npZ35bGLiPkmVqaw5l4J?p=preview

Comment: can't see the image, can you put a jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes sorry, the image doesn't seem to be working. Just added a plunk there

Comment: I've compared my code to the code from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and cant see any difference really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Ashesh said you had the angular paths wrong, you also have a **working** example on [Angular Ui Team](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for the accordion control.

live example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6zhm49PCgPZr8wKD5Szr?p=preview

Comment: I did just use the working example in the end, but I couldn't figure out where mine was going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You had the angular paths wrong, [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/JmaHAxhT87ldinbOXf82), for example, gets the job done. You can start from there.

Comment: That only had the add working, but the accordion menu didn't work. I just took the one off the Angular UI team github http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ .